# Fill Create form with default values from API call in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm still quite unexperienced with React and react-admin. I searched a lot of resources but couldn't find any valuable hints. My use case is the following:

### Status Quo

Here is an example of one of my `List` components. This provides the default button to create a new item which redirects the user to the `Create` view.

```
export const CountryList = props => (
  <List
    sort={{ field: "name", order: "ASC" }}
    filters={<CountryListFilter />}
    {...props}
  >
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="name" />
      <TextField source="iso3" />
      <EditButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

### Desired Behavior

Instead of an empty `Create` form I'd like to provide dynamic default values. If the user clicks on the "Create" button in the `List` view I'd like the following to happen:

1. The application issues a custom GET request to an external server (outside the scope of the already defined dataProvider)
2. The response data from that request is used to populate the `Create` form.

While I know how to use e.g. axios to issue the GET request, I counldn't figure out:

- Where/on which trigger would I issue the request?
- How would I pass the reponse data to the form's default values?

My idea was that I can somehow "overload" the default functionality of the create button.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've never used react-admin, but I will try to help you.

- Where/on which trigger would I issue the request?

In your "Create" button there should be a onClick event function. And you issue the request there and invoke this.setState in order to re-render your component

- How would I pass the reponse data to the form's default values?

Via state or props :)

My idea would be something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Example extends Component {
  state = { input: "default" }

  handleInputChange = evt => {
    console.log("user changing input")
    this.setState({ input: evt.target.value });
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("user clicked the button")
    // server request part...
    .then(data => this.setState({input: data}))
  }

  render() { 
    return ( <div>
      <input value={this.state.input} type="text" placeholder="ISO" onChange={evt => this.handleInputChange(evt)}></input>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick()}></button>
    </div> );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

I really don't know if I made you more confused :/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I forget to mention that the `Create` button is already provided by react-admin itself, i.e. it's not a button I have defined myself.